# Animating calayers follow finger location constantly

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation

I have a UIView contains many UILabels. Now I long press one of labels then the others will fly to the pressed one with animation, the others will follow my finger location constantly.

**My question is**

1. How can i perform this task with core animation?
2. In my solution,the animation is extremely sluggish when label number greater than 20. Why?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
        [super viewDidLoad];
        _longGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressGestureUpdated:)];
        _longGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        [[self dragView] addGestureRecognizer:_longGesture];
}
- (void)longPressGestureUpdated:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)longPressGesture
{
    switch (longPressGesture.state) 
    {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        {
            location = [longPressGesture locationInView:self.view];
            [self startAllLayersAnimation];
            break;
        }
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:  
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
        {
           location = [longPressGesture locationInView:self.view];
            [self startAllLayersAnimation];
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
- (void)startAllLayersAnimation
{
    [CATransaction begin];
    for (CALayer *layer in [self labelLayers]) 
    {
        [self startAnimation:layer];
    }
    [CATransaction commit];
}
- (void)startAnimation:(CALayer*)layer
{
    CGPoint now =((CALayer*)layer.presentationLayer).position;
    CABasicAnimation * cab = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    cab.delegate = self;
    cab.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    cab.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    cab.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:now];
    cab.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:location];
    cab.duration = 1;
    //cab.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
    [layer addAnimation:cab forKey:@"revItUpAnimation"];
}
```

Is my solution right? Could tell me how can I perform this method more appropriately ?

Comment: You posted code that already uses Core Animation. You have an animation duration of 1 second, with ease out timing. 1 second is a pretty slow animation.

What is sluggish, the initial animation or the finger-following animating that comes after? You haven't shown that part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using gestures try and use`UITouch` . It will help as the 2 events of `touchesBegan`and `touchesMoved` will include your `CABasicAnimation` methods.

Comment: touchesMoved will trigger many startAnimations be called,i think nothing will change.Can you explain it more detailly